# iOS autolayout constraint violation when device orientation is changed

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, uistackview, size-classes

I have an autolayout layout that has been created for an iPhone in portrait mode.

When I rotate the device from portrait to landscape I get a warning saying the system cannot satisfy two constraints at the same time.  This happens when rotating to and from both orientation.

[image]

I believe I have found the offending constraint (highlighted below), and it is one generated by iOS, moving my constraint that is in conflict breaks my layout and causes more constraint violation errors.

The layout works visually; so long as I ignore the warning.

The layout consists of two basic parts, a control parts (using a `UIStackView` that is 30% of the height of the device) and a `UITableView` that fills the remaining area.  These are embedded in a `UIStackView` that is set to cover the default `UIView` with margins to the safe area.

[image]

To make best use of the the available screen space when the device is rotated to landscape the control part should go from above the `UITableView` to beside it, and take up 45% of the width of the screen.

The conflicting constraint is on the "controller" part of the view setting its leading edge to be 16 points from the superviews leading edge.

Is there away to get around this? I don't like too, but can the warning be ignored?

I have tried embedding the main `UIStackView` in a `UIView` and removing the constraint that is in conflict; but his causes other issues unless I add in constraints between the `UIView` and `UIStackView` which then have the same conflicting constraints issue.

A repo for an example project with the same issue can be found [at](https://github.com/gavintranter/Experiment).

When simplifying the layout it appears I am unable to have a `UIStackView` with `Alignment = Fill`, `Distribution = Fill Equally` and `Spacing = 5` (or standard spacing) as the spacing on the `UIStackView` appears to be. in conflict.

Comment: Could you add a warning text, a screenshot with constraints and a screenshot with UI hierarchy? With additional information should be much easer to help you.

Comment: Hope the updates help.  I was going to have a go at putting together an example project, to see if I could replicate it in simpler form.

Comment: Looking at the example project, I see that your _info stack view_ is the responsible for the warning. You have a proportional height constraint set for the info stack view and you have specified distribution as `Fill Proportionally`. These two contradicts with each other. Hence you are getting the warning (though its a misleading warning to be honest). Either you use `Fill` or `Fill Equally` distribution for the info stack view and adjust the spacing value as your need.

Comment: @Gavin I made a PR at your example project's repository. Feel free to check that out in order to eliminate extraneous constraints.

Comment: Thanks I have merged it.  I think it is good to remove constraints that are not needed, less chance of conflicts :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's common to see these types of constraint warnings when using Vary for Traits.

You can get rid of the constraint conflicts on rotation by changing the `Priority` on both of your proportional constraints on `Info Stack View` to `999`.

When I run your Experiment app, I also see a constraint conflict on your `Detail Stack View` ... but, it looks like an internal conflict that you may not be able to get rid of. Changing that stack view's `Distribution` to `Fill Equally` instead of `Fill Proportionally` clears it, but that may not give you the exact layout you're looking for.

`Fill Proportionally` seems to be the most misunderstood and misused setting... I'd suggest modifying your layout to avoid that... Probably by embedding `Detail Stack View` in a `UIView`, `Distribution: Fill`, and constraining it to be centered in that `UIView`.

Comment: You are right, it does mess up my layout; but at least its messed up and not broken :) Thanks